# Arabic font numbers not working in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, fonts, arabic

I am using "MSH-Quraan1" font for the Arabic text in my app. I have added the MSH-Quraan1.tff file in the project. Included it in the `info.plist` file as well. When I am loading Arabic text,i.e., with out numbers, the text is using the font. But when I load the text along with the numbers, the number are not converting, and it is displaying in English numericals.

I even tried localizing the numbers but nothing is happening. When localize the text it works, but not the numbers.

Please help.

**Update**

I think the ASCII character of Arabic numbers and English numbers are different due to which it is unable to recognize the characters.

Comment: did your fonts contain numbers also? if yes give me font file i will try to do it. my mail id is mentioned in profile if you need.

Comment: Yes. Its Uthamni font. With the font-family as 'Msh Quraan1' and font-name as 'MSH-Quraan1' in the iOS font list. And i cant see your mail id in your profile.

Comment: my mail id is niravjain02@gmail.com. send me project file or font file.

Comment: I mailed you the font.

Answer (score 0):

I face issue sometime ago. Can you please look into this converter which will work smoothly in your scenario.

Try it if possilbe : https://github.com/Accorpa/Arabic-Converter-From-and-To-Arabic-Presentation-Forms-B

After using this library text and numeric numbers are working fine for me. If you find any issue using this library just contact me.

(**Note : Your font file contains arabic numbers as well.**)